# Getting scrollable content in an Onsen Modal (React)

Tags: reactjs, onsen-ui

I've created a Modal in Onsen which works great, but sometimes my content spans beyond the page boundaries.  The Modal does not naturally support scrolling and the `<Scrollable />` element is not supported by the React support in Onsen so I've attempted to make a `<section/>` scrollable like so:

```
   <Modal isOpen={this.state.selected.title !== undefined} onDeviceBackButton={()=> this.setState({selected: {}})}>
        <section style={{margin: '16px', overflow: 'auto', height: '100%'}}>
             <h2>{this.state.selected.title}</h2>
             {myReallyLongContent}
        </section>
    </Modal>;
```

This appears to work when testing on my desktop browser (in "Chrome Mobile testing"); however, when testing on my actual mobile device, the scrolling does not work (via touch swiping).  Is there a workaround?